# why this recursive programis having garbage value even after assignment

Tags: c, gcc

The values in image appear from nowhere:

[image: the values in image appear from nowhere]

What are these values and if they are garbage values then why they are still present after assigning **J** the value. I am also attaching the source code.

```
int sum(int); 
void main()
{
        int a, b;
        int j = 0;
        printf("please enter the number to find the sum\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &a); 
        j = a + 1;
        printf("%d\n", j);
        b = sum(j);
        printf("the sum is %d", b);
} 
int sum(int j) {
    printf("jis %d\n", j);
    int f;
    if (j == 0)
    {
        printf("if cond\n");
        return f;
    }
    else
    {
        j = j - 1;
        printf("f up is %d\n", f);

        f = j + sum(j);
        printf("f dw is %d\n", f);
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont post pictures of text, post text as text.

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` block of function `sum`, you declare `int f` without assigning it a value and hence it possesses a garbage value. The only time you assign it a value is after the statement `printf("f up is %d\n",f);`. Hence, this statement is always going to print a garbage value.

Comment: yes I didn't initialized i but why does the garbage value stays even after 2 recursion calls

Comment: Because every call initializes it as at a different location. If you think that `int f` would retain its value just because you use the recursive calls use the same name, you are wrong. If you want that to happen, you have to define the variable globally.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an uninitialized variable, that will lead to undefined behavior . and you have used uninitialized `int f` in your `if-else`statement in `sum` function. Initialize it.

Also don't use `void main` use `int main`.

Comment: yeah i know that i didn't initialized it but the values continue to be there after 2 recursion calls why??

Comment: @abhishek the reason is what  Param Siddharth said .read that comment.